# Adding two strings together in python

Tags: python, variables, syntax, syntax-error, variable-declaration

I'm trying to place two strings together but when I run this code I keep getting an error.
I'm sure this is something basic but I ahave been playing with this for 30 minutes and can't figure out what's wrong

```
filename= 'data.txt'
1output = '1min' + filename
```

Comment: You can't start a variable name with a number.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like most languages, Python does not allow you to create a name that starts with a number.  This means that you need to rename `1output` because its name is illegal:

```
output1 = '1min' + filename
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> filename = 'data.txt'
>>> 1output = '1min' + filename
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1output = '1min' + filename
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> filename = 'data.txt'
>>> output1 = '1min' + filename
>>> output1
'1mindata.txt'
>>>
```

When creating names in Python, you must obey the following rules*:

1. The first character must be either a letter or an underscore.
2. The rest of the characters must be letters, underscores, and/or numbers.
3. The finished name cannot be the same as one of the [keywords](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) (`if`, `def`, `for`, etc.).

---

***Note:** In addition, you should refrain from creating a name that is the same as one of the [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) (`str`, `input`, `list`, etc.).  While doing so *is* legal, it is considered a bad practice by many Python coders (author included).  This is because it will overshadow the built-in and thereby make it unusable in the current scope.